# Understanding slow Bitmap Heap Scan in LIKE query

Tags: sql, postgresql

The following query run on Postgres

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM "posts"
WHERE "posts"."author_id" = 20
AND ("posts"."title" ILIKE '123');
```

apparently involves a really slow bitmap heap scan. How can I can diagnose the reason why this is so slow? And what could I do to have it perform better?

```
my-app::DATABASE=> EXPLAIN ANALYZE VERBOSE
my-app::DATABASE-> SELECT COUNT(*)
my-app::DATABASE-> FROM "posts"
my-app::DATABASE-> WHERE "posts"."author_id" = 20
my-app::DATABASE-> AND ("posts"."title" ILIKE '123');
                                                                            QUERY PLAN                                                                            
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=25516.64..25516.64 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=35632.267..35632.267 rows=1 loops=1)
   Output: count(*)
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on public.posts  (cost=307.46..25516.64 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=35632.264..35632.264 rows=0 loops=1)
         Recheck Cond: (posts.author_id = 20)
         Filter: ((posts.title)::text ~~* '123'::text)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 22216
         Heap Blocks: exact=15419
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_posts_on_author_id_and_state  (cost=0.00..307.46 rows=23586 width=0) (actual time=54.585..54.585 rows=22235 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (posts.author_id = 20)
 Planning time: 0.853 ms
 Execution time: 35632.405 ms
(11 rows)
```

Comment: Why do you use `ILIKE` when there's no wildcard?

Comment: It was to just explore the query strategy but in general it might search by suffixes or prefixes.

Comment: Create an index on `(author_id, title)` if title is not very big

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way the query is written, no index can make it better.

But you could rewrite it like this:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM posts
WHERE posts.author_id = 20
AND lower(posts.title) LIKE lower('abc%');
```

Then the following index can help *in some cases*:

```
CREATE INDEX posts_auth_title_ind
   ON posts (
      author_id,
      lower(title) text_pattern_ops
   );
```

`text_pattern_ops` is required for `LIKE` unless you are using the `C` or `POSIX` collation.

If the search pattern starts with a wildcard, no B-tree index can help. You can try [`pg_tgrm`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html) indexes in that case.